# Simple dictionary search engine

Tags: php, dictionary, search-engine

I have a code that's suppose to run a dictionary search engine and I just started and stuck. here's my full code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title><center>Dictionary</center></title>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>
<center>

<form action="" method=get>
<input type=text name=query style="font:11px arial; font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFDD;">
<input type=submit name=submit  >
</form>

<br>



<br>
<br>
<table width=400 align=center><tr><td>

  <?php

$txt_file= file_get_contents('dcdocument.txt');// << i put a path over here
 $rows= explode("\n", $txt_file);


 foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{ 
    //i have a long list of words and separated the words from definition using":::"
 if ($row_data = ':::'){
  explode(':::', $data);
 };
 
    $row_data = explode('::::', $data);
 ?>
  
  
</table>



<br> <br>
</center>
</form>
</body>

<html>
```

What I'm pretty much trying to do is the user enters word(s) into the search engine and when they press 'search', the definition show up. I know it's a bad start but I need all the help I can get to save tons of time. Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck? You should look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php rather than `file_get_contents` and `explode`.

Comment: Iam not sure what error you are getting. I had a question do you have the file dcdocument.txt some where . if so it seems your code is reading from that.. what is the content of the file

Comment: It doesn't show anything, when I search for a word, it just shows blank.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to build a search engine, you can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match the strings with what the user has searched for.

Comment: I just added 'preg_match( $row, 'query') ? true : false echo $row_data;'  before last line and it keeps on showing error. and I tried 'print_r($rowdata)'. can you help.

Comment: It will cause an error as you have not defined $rowdata to be the result of the `preg_match` call. Also, you have gotten the syntax wrong. Please read the documentation for the function using the link I have provided. 

You will want to use $data and not $row as $row will store the index.